# How to find the number of intersection for $ \rho =\frac{\theta} {2\pi+1} $ and $\rho =\frac {1} {2-\cos\theta} $

Tags: polar-coordinates

How  to Find the number of intersection for curve $ \rho =\frac{\theta} {2\pi+1} $ and curve   $\rho =\frac {1} {2-\cos\theta} $  .

Comment: If graphical way is OK, then answer follows immediately as $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\cos{\theta}=2-\dfrac{2\pi+1}{\theta}, 1 \ge \cos{\theta} \ge -1 \to 1 \ge 2-\dfrac{2\pi+1}{\theta} \ge -1 \iff 3 \ge \dfrac{2\pi+1}{\theta} \ge 1 \iff 2\pi+1 \ge  \theta \ge \dfrac{2\pi+1}{3}$

$\dfrac{\pi}{4} < 1 < \dfrac{\pi}{3} \to 2\pi + \dfrac{\pi}{3} > \theta > \dfrac{2\pi}{3}+\dfrac{\pi}{12}=\dfrac{3\pi}{4}$, now divide the domain into 4 segments:

$[\dfrac{3\pi}{4},\pi] ;[\pi,\dfrac{3\pi}{2}],[\dfrac{3\pi}{2},2\pi],[2\pi,2\pi + \dfrac{\pi}{3}]$

let $g(\theta)=2-\dfrac{2\pi+1}{\theta}$

in $[\dfrac{3\pi}{4},\pi], \cos{\theta} $ from $-\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ to $-1,g(\theta)$ from $-1$ to $-\dfrac{1}{\pi}$ , they will corss each.(explain yourself)

in $[\pi,\dfrac{3\pi}{2}], \cos{\theta} $ from $-1$ to $0,g(\theta) $ from $-\dfrac{1}{\pi}$ to $\dfrac{2(\pi-1)}{3\pi}$,what happen to $ \cos{\theta},g(\theta)$.

I think you can do rest now.

Edit: I add two graphics to show the result:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I use computer drawing, also get four intersections.  but do not know how to explain. Thank you.

Comment: I have little doubt: this formula $\cos{\theta}=2-\dfrac{2\pi+1}{\theta}$  is not equivalent subject conditions   , after all, polar coordinates and Cartesian coordinate system is different than one to one.

Comment: it is same result to use analytic method no matter which kind of coordinate system used. you want to find intersections, it means you have to find solution from the equations.BTW, the result is 3. see the graphics I added.

Comment: $\theta $  can be negative 

 four intersections.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

$\theta $  can be negative

four intersections.